# Help with logic notation, what are $S$ and $\underline0$?

Tags: notation, predicate-logic

This is a more or less literal translation from German, hopefully it's understandable, it's all the information available:

> Let $L_N=\{\underline0,S,+,\cdot~,<\}$ be the language of the natural numbers and let $\mathcal A$ be the $L_N$-structure with underlying set $\mathbb N$.
>   Furthermore, $\beta$ is a variable assignment with $\beta(v_n)=2n ~\forall n \in \mathbb N_0$.
>
> Calculate
>
> - $t_1^{\mathcal A}[\beta]$, where $t_1=\underline0$
> - $t_2^{\mathcal A}[\beta]$, where $t_2=(S(S(\underline0))\cdot v_{2016} +(S(v_{2015})+t_1))$
> - $t_3^{\mathcal A}[\beta]$, where $t_3=S(t_1)\cdot t_1$

Now, are $S$ and $\underline0$ so common I should know what is meant or are they "irrelevant" to solving the task? I can remember seeing something similar at the Peano axioms, so $S(S(\underline0))$ would be $2$, but then why the underline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This $\beta$ appears to be what is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Evaluation_of_truth_values) called a *variable assignment*. $S$ is a unary function symbol that is intended to be interpreted as the successor function in $\Bbb N$, and $\underline{0}$ is a constant symbol that is intended to be interpreted as $0\in\Bbb N$.

**Added:** And on cross-checking with [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4dikatenlogik_erster_Stufe#Interpretationen), I see that in this context a *Belegung* is indeed a variable assignment.